# Cscart 301 redirect to Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, redirect, http-status-code-301, cs-cart

i am trying to redirect from a Cscart url to a Opencart url but it seems that it does not work.

Old url (cscart)

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=1430
```

new url (opencart)

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=1746
```

I want to do this manual for the first 10 main categories and all other subcategories from cscart to redirect to the https://www.example.com home page.

How can i succeed this?
Also, the new url uses https.

Thank you in advance
-Konstantinos

Answer (score 0):

A simple, manual way would be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dispatch=categories.view&category_id=1430
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=1746 [R,L]
```

and so on for all other category mappings.

---

An alternative could be to capture the old `category_id` and use it with [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) in the `RewriteRule` substitution URI

```
RewriteMap categories txt:/path/to/categories.txt

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dispatch=categories.view&category_id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=${categories:%1} [R,L]
```

And in the file `categories.txt`, you would have a mapping from old to new category ids

```
1430 1746
123 456
987 333
```

See also [txt: Plain text maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) for more details, or alternatives to plain text mappings.

The drawback of this method, you cannot use it in an .htaccess file, only in the main configuration or virtual host section.

---

When everything works as it should, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Hi Olaf and thank you! I have added the following but i get a 500 internal server error. The code is the following: `#RewriteMap categories txt:/httpdocs/newsite/htaccess/rewrite_categories.txt

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dispatch=categories.view&category_id=(\d+)
#RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=${categories:%1} [R,L] `

Comment: Also, my htaccess_categories.txt is the following format as you suggested: `451 1764
402 2101
529 1773
433 1893
476 2101
436 2157_2176
432 2157_2176
1450 2157_2176
552 2157_2176
1264 2157_2176
697 2157_2176
873 2157_2176
688 2157_2176`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you cannot use `RewriteMap` in .htaccess files, only in the main config or virtual host section. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: So it seems you must use the manual method, one rule per mapping.

Comment: I have about 800 categories that need to be redirected, its really difficult to do all the redirections by hand.. Any other alternative?

Comment: When you have access to the main/virtual host config, you can use RewriteMap as described. When you have the category mapping in a file, you could create the "manual" rules with a simple script. You can also think about some sort of a PHP front controller doing the mapping.